# Matlab Vectorization for nested for loops with 2D matrices

Tags: matlab, for-loop, 2d, vectorization, nested-loops

ok guys, I have edited the question.

```
results = zeros(96,96);
for a=1:96
    for b=1:85
        results(a,b) = abs(input(a,b) - input(a,(b+11)))
    end
end
```

input is also a 96x96 matrix.

Can you please help me to vectorize the loops.

Comment: Shouldn't there be pre-allocation for `results` and the iterators start from `1`?

Comment: And in addition to Divakar's comment, why not do `for b=1:85` and eliminate the `if`-statement?

Comment: Also please avoid using variable names that are identical to MATLAB built-in function names - `input` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified to match the edited question, and changing the name of the input matrix to avoid conflicts with matlab keywords.  You end up with a 96x85 matrix occupying the first 85 rows of the zero matrix you initialized:

```
results = zeros(96,96);
results(:,1:85) = abs(inputMatrix(:,1:85) - inputMatrix(:,12:end))
```

Comment: You need to pad with zeros or pre-allocate it seems.